# Find the number of roots of the equation, $x^3 + x^2 +2x +\sin x = 0$ in $[-2\pi , 2\pi]$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Find the number of roots of the equation,
>   $$x^3 + x^2 +2x +\sin x = 0$$
>   in $[-2\pi , 2\pi]$.

What I have tried:
$$x^3 + x^2 +2x = -\sin x$$
$$x^2 +x +2 = \frac{-\sin x }{x}$$
$$(x + \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{7}{4} = \frac{-\sin x }{x}$$

I am getting somewhere from here, but I don't know how to continue. Please help!

***The answer is 1***

Comment: Note that $x=0$ is a solution, and that $x>0$ implies $x^3 + x^2 +2x +\sin x>0$.

Comment: @Servaes It is might be one of the solutions, but how do you know all of them...

Comment: Have you considered the derivative?

Comment: @Servaes How does it help here?

Comment: If, for example, the derivative is positive/negative on the entire interval, then the function is strictly increasing/decreasing, so it cannot take any value more than once.

Comment: I think OP tried the right way. Obviously $x=0$ is one root. For $x\neq0$, OP obtained $(x+\frac12)^2+\frac74=-\frac{\sin x}{x}$. Note that the LHS is at least $\frac74$, but the RHS is at most $1$. So there is no $x\in\mathbb R$ satisfying the equation. Therefore $x=0$ is the unique root.

Comment: @Eric Yau Is it immediately clear that the RHS is at most $1$?

Comment: @Servaes Yeah, $0<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1$

Comment: Ok then there's your answer :)

Comment: Yup I got it. Thanks @Servaes

Comment: Thanks @EricYau

Comment: Note that for $x=\tfrac{3\pi}{2}$ you have $\tfrac{\sin x}{x}=-\tfrac{2}{3\pi}<0$ though.

Comment: It takes some machinery to show that $0 \lt \frac{\sin x}{x} \lt 1$.  If you know that much, I'd be inclined to just take derivatives and find the local extrema.

Comment: FYI, there is one somewhat elementary proof of $|\sin x|\le|x|$. We may assume $x>0$ and further assume $x<1$. Now $0<x<1$. Draw a circle of radius $1$. Then $x$ is the length of some arc $\overset\frown{AC}$ and $\sin x$ is the length of some segment $AB$. It is not hard to see that $|AB|<|AC|<|\overset\frown{AC}|$. Here $|\cdots|$ means length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall x~(f'(x)=3x^2+2x+2+\cos x \gt 0)$ (the polynomial term is always at least $5/3$), so note that $f(-2 \pi) \lt 0, f(2 \pi) \gt 0$ and conclude that there is exactly $1$ root.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, I knew the solution to this question. So, I am just writing it out as an answer.

For the case where $x \ne 0$,
$$(x+\frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{7}{4} = - \frac{\sin x}{x}$$
Since, LHS is at least $\frac{7}{4}$ 
From the comment of Eric Yau, $0<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1$ and hence, $-1 < \frac{\sin x}{x} < 0$

Hence for $ x \ne 0 $, there is no solution for x.
However, clearly by substituting 0, $x=0$ is definitely a root of this equation.

Hence, $x=0$ is the only solution for this equation and thus, there is only one root for this equation.

Comment: I was saying $|\frac{\sin x}{x}|\le1$. $0<\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not correct in general.

Answer (score 1):

For $x<0, \sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5)>x$:
$$x^3+x^2+2x-\sin x <x^3+x^2+2x-x=x(x^2+x+1)<0,$$
for $x>0, \sin x<x$:
$$x^3+x^2+2x-\sin x>x^3+x^2+2x-x=x^3+x^2+x>0.$$